# How to send few specific contacts to my old basic phone?

Tags: contacts, google-contacts

I am having a Moto G and Nexus 7 (2012, WiFi only) devices which have my contacts synced with my Google account.

My Moto G suffered a hardware issue because of which I am using a very basic phone for my calling needs. I have given the Moto G for service and it would take a week for them to fix.

My basic replacement phone (Nokia 1800) does not have Bluetooth, no WiFi, No packet data support. Since my SIM and the new phones are devoid of any contacts,I could not see who is calling me and to make calls, I resorted to pen and paper method.

**I am just wondering whether there could be any means of sending few of my contacts from my Google account to the SIM via SMS**.

Another way I could try is to use someone else Android phone to access my google account and copy selected to my SIM. But I see that's too much of trouble to others as they might not be willing to lend.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a relatively simple description of the desired process:

- Download your contacts from Google by following the simple instructions [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/24911?hl=en)
- Open your e-mail program and start a new e-mail message.
- Enter the cell phone number in the To: box using the format number@teleflip.com, where "number" is the phone number of the cell phone to which you're sending the message. For example, to send a text message to cell phone 123-456-7890, enter 1234567890@teleflip.com.(in this case you want to **enter your own cell number**) *Please see [source](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/e-mail-messaging/how-to-send-text-messages-computer.htm) for more information*
- Type a message of up to 160 characters in the message box and then click **Send** (in this case, attempt to **attach the contacts file that you exported from your Google account instead of a message!**) .
  Congratulations! Your message will shortly appear on the cell phone.
  Hope this helps! Good luck

Comment: Thanks, my operator (BSNL,India) seems not to have any such way to send an email and receive it as a SMS.

Comment: Not even "your_number"@teleflip.com works?

Comment: Attempts like 91mynumber@bsnl.co,in, sms.bsnl.co.in, .bsnl.in, .sms.bsnl.in and the same combination with absense of country code 91 tried. All resulted in bouncing email. Sending to 91mynumber@teleflip.com and mynumber@teleflip.com does not bounce, but no reply nor sms.